# SQL Join two tables with an excluding condition?

Tags: sql, join

I have a SQL question which I am trying to solve. Below is the question:

Given the following two tables write a SQL query that returns the 
top 10000 scores excluding uuids that have any what=3 events in the 
last 30 days.

```
TABLE scores (
  uuid INT,
  score FLOAT
)
TABLE events (
  when date,
  uuid INT, 
  what INT
)
```

I tried to solve it in this way by dividing the question into two statements and then joining it,

For the statement: SQL query that returns the top 10000 scores, I got,

```
SELECT TOP 10000 score FROM scores;
```

For the statement:uuids that have any what=3 events in the last 30 days.

```
SELECT uuid FROM events WHERE what=3 AND when>2/14/2015;
```

By joining the two statements based on the excluding condition, i got,

```
SELECT TOP 10000 score
WHERE what!=3 AND when>2/14/2015
FROM scores
INNER JOIN events
ON score.uuid=events.uuid;
```

But I am not sure if this correct, and I feel like I am missing something here like a specific syntax for "excluding", and also I am not sure if I performed the Join operation in the right way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select top 10000 score
from scores
where not exists(
     select 1 
     from events
     where scores.uuid = events.uuid
     and events.when > 20150214 
     and what=3 
    )
```

Comment: I'm upvoting, but you might as well use the ISO format `'2015-02-14'` most databases understand this in a date context (although in Oracle you need to prepend it with the keyword "date".  I also presume an `order by` is needed for the `top`, but the question is vague on the field to use.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: That's almost correct. The *one and only* date format guaranteed to be correctly recognized in all cultures and regions in 'yyyymmdd' (ie `'20150214'` in this instance) with no delimiters.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens . . . I know that, and I know the SQL Server limitations in this area.  I still maintain that YYYY-MM-DD is ISO standard and readable.  I am a human, after all.  By the way, other databases will not necessarily recognize that format.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Readability is important - but slighlly less so than being functionally correct.

Comment: Edited the answer as per your comments.